# Homework: Is the triangle an equilateral triangle?

Tags: geometry, triangles

A triangle is drawn inside a circle with it's corners on the circle alongside the following conditions:
$$AB = AC,$$
$$\angle ABM = \angle CBM$$ and
$MB$ is the radius which equal $1$ length unit.

How to prove the triangle also is an equilateral triangle?

[image: "drawing of the triangle"]

Comment: We're not here to do your homework for you without any effort on your part. What have you tried?

Comment: @Blex yes, I know it's isosceles but I need help explaining how to prove it. AB=AC doesn't mean AB=AC=BC

Comment: @Shaun I've tried drawing in CM and AM which makes two congruent triangles(AMB and CMB) but can't prove CMB is it aswell(?). Also tried drawing the normal from AC to M, but can't prove it becomes a straight line with MB

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: Construct lines AM and MC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the help everyone!

$△BMC => ∠MCB = ∠MBC$ because $MB = MC$
Same goes for $△AMB$ which is $≅$ to $△CMA$ because three equal sides.
This means $∠ABM = ∠BCM = ∠CAM = ∠ACM = ∠CBM = ∠BAC$ (every angle is the same except the middle ones). Adding the angles sharing a side and you get three equal angels which mean it is an equilateral triangle.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Generally speaking, you should accept  one of the answers once you're satisfied. If you want to edit your original post or add these details as a comment to one of the answers, feel free to do so. :) Glad we could help.

Answer (score 2):

You mean that you want to show the triangle is *equilateral*, not *isosceles*. In fact, this is true. Draw in $AM$ and $CM$ and consider all the angles. Remember that you know that $\angle ABC \cong \angle ACB$.

Comment: okay so I drew in those but I can't be sure CM splits ∠BCA through the middle of the angle?

Comment: Use all your information. You have a lot of isosceles triangles flying around.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Draw in $AM$ and $CM$. You will get three isosceles triangles.

Answer (score 0):

Since $AB=AC$, we obtain $\gamma=\beta$ and

since $\measuredangle ABM=90^{\circ}-\gamma$ and $\measuredangle MBC=90^{\circ}-\alpha$, we obtain $\gamma=\alpha$ and we are done!